# Openlayers 6: how do i get all clusters to stack with eachother

Tags: javascript, html-lists, openlayers

i was wondering how i would get all clusters to stack with eachother and not ontop of eachother

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSDLo.jpg

This is what it looks like right now but i want the clusters to stack to eachothers when they are different layers

```
var TowerLayer = new ol.layer.AnimatedCluster({
title: 'Towers',
name: 'Cluster',
source: new ol.source.Cluster({
distance: 40,
source: new ol.source.Vector({
features: Towers
})
}),
animationDuration: 700,
style: TowerStyle
});

var ChimneyLayer = new ol.layer.AnimatedCluster({
title: 'Chimneys',
name: 'Cluster',
source: new ol.source.Cluster({
distance: 40,
source: new ol.source.Vector({
features: Chimneys
})
}),
animationDuration: 700,
style: ChimneyStyle
});
```

Heres how im creating the layers

```
TowerLayer.getSource().getSource().clear();
 
TowerLayer.getSource().getSource().addFeatures(Towers); ChimneyLayer.getSource().getSource().clear()
ChimneyLayer.getSource().getSource().addFeatures(Chimneys):
```

and then heres how im adding the clusters to the layers.

i tried to search around on google for an answer and didnt really get a clear one

Comment: What do you mean by "stack to eachothers when they are different layers"?  Do you want the clusters to cluster data from all the layers?  Or to appear on top of each other?  Or to not overlap at all?

Comment: @geocodezip So i want the clusters to appear as 1 cluster when im zoomed out completely, idk how to since im creating 5 different layers for cluster

Comment: You will need to put your features in a single source to cluster them together.  Use a style function to style them according to what type of features the clusters contain.